# PHP failed to get returned value from mailer

Tags: php, get, phpmailer

I have a contact form on my website.
I want to make the PHP mailer work where I get the input from the form and **return 1 for success** otherwise **return -1 in error**. I want to include that,  I have collected the mailer file.

This is the error I was getting.

> Notice: Undefined index: success in C:\xampp\htdocs\omnifood\index.php

This php code get the value that was returned by the mailer.php file.

```
<?php
if ($_GET['success'] == 1) {
    echo "<div class=\"form-message success\"> Thank you. Your message has been sent ! </div>";
}
if ($_GET['success'] == -1) {
    echo "<div class=\"form-message error\"> Opps! Something went wrong. Please try again. </div>";
} 
?>
```

Here is the code that returns the value if any error happens.

```
if (empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: localhost:8080/omnifood/index.php?success=-1#form");
    exit;
}
```

After successfully sending the mail, it will return.

```
header("Location: localhost:8080/omnifood/index.php?success=1#form");
```

Comment: you should check if the key `success` even exists in the array `$_GET`. E.g. you could do `isset($_GET['success'])`

Comment: This basically says that there is no such thing as `success` in the url. You sure you're sending it along?